# How to give extensions in httppostedfilebase in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LogoPath, new { @id = "_LogoPath" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HttpPostedFile, "", new { @type = "file", @id = "FileDocument"
, @class = "custom-file-input" })
```

Comment: Like File type `extension`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LogoPath, new { @id = "_LogoPath" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HttpPostedFile, "", new { @type = "file", @id = "FileDocument",accept=".png,.jpeg,.docx,.pdf", @class = "custom-file-input" })
```